# serverless deploy error - Resource handler returned message: "Lambda function xxxxxxxx could not be found"

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Hi can anyone help me how to deploy serverless with specific stage, I have 1 app with 2 stage `dev` and `prod`. When deploy to `dev` its working fine and successfully deployed, but with `prod` stage always get below error:

```
Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: FilterOptionLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Lambda function xxxxxxx-api-prod-xxxxxx could not be found" (RequestToken: ee621797-de45-aa3f-118b-8f512d4a5f62, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)
```

I tried to comment all function and leave 1 function to test deploy, but received another error as below:

```
Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: EnterpriseLogAccessIamRole (AWS::IAM::Role)
Unable to retrieve Arn attribute for AWS::Logs::LogGroup, with error message Resource of type 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup' with identifier '{"/properties/LogGroupName":"/aws/lambda/xxxxx-api-prod-api"}' was not found.
```

Here is my `serverless.yml`:

```
org: xxxxxx
app: comeby-api
service: comeby-scheduler-api
frameworkVersion: "3"

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
  
  myEnvironment:
    MESSAGE:
      prod: "This is production environment"
      staging: "This is staging environment"
      dev: "This is development environment"

useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: ap-southeast-1
  stage: prod

functions:
  api:
    handler: handler.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: "*"

  # Alikhsan
  SyncAlikhsanSB2: 
  SyncAlikhsanAMT:
  SyncAlikhsanASG:  
  SyncAlikhsanIOI:  
  SyncAlikhsanJSB:  
  SyncAlikhsanSPY:
    
  # Sync Product
  Shopify:  
  SyncSenheng:
  SyncXilnix:
  Puma:
  
  # Anything
  FilterOption:
  AriadneMaps:
    handler: scheduler/update/AriadneMaps.handler
    description: "Update Ariadne Maps (to view report of total visitor of specific store) in Database"
    memorySize: 512
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(00 22 * * ? *)
          enabled: true
      - http:
          path: /cron/ariadne
          method: get
  SendEmailUpdateProduct:
  ReportPurchasing:
  UpdateProductPricePuma:
  UpdateFootFallCam:
  
plugins:
  # - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-offline-scheduler
```

[image]

Comment: What is the deployment command that you are using?

Comment: @ReazMurshed `sls deploy --stage prod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing from those `UPDATE_FAILED`s, you are using the same serverless file for both dev and prod deployment. Based on this assumption, you may have to provide separate service names for both of your deployments. If you have deployed to the `dev` environment already with service name `comeby-scheduler-api`, the next deployment for prod stage with the same service name will try to override the previous deployment.

In my case, I tackled this using 2 separate serverless configuration files (one for dev and the other for prod). For `dev` deployment, my config file `serverless-dev.yml` looks like the following.

```
service: service-dev

provider:
  name: aws
  role: arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<my-lambda-role-name>
  region: <region>
  runtime: python3.8
  environment:
    DB_HOST: <host>
    DB_PASSWORD: <pass>
    DB_PORT: <port>
    DB_DATABASE: <db_name>
    DB_USER: <db_user>
    
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-secrets-plugin
  - serverless-api-compression

package:
  patterns:
    - '!venv/**'
    - '!__pycache__/**'
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!test/**'

functions:
  Lambda1:
    handler: lambda_file_name.handler_function_name
    memorySize: 512
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: <bucket_name_for_this_lambda_trigger>
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: <filter_trigger_file_prefix>
            - suffix: <filter_trigger_file_suffix>
          existing: <true if an existing s3 bucket, false otherwise>
```

Whereas for the `prod`, the `serverless-prod.yml` file is,

```
service: service-prod

provider:
  name: aws
  role: arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<my-lambda-role-name>
  region: <region>
  runtime: python3.8

... rest is similar
```

My deployment commands for these separate stages are.

```
sls deploy -s dev -c serverless-dev.yml
sls deploy -s prod -c serverless-prod.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

This error also occured for me because I had previously setup another (unrelated) service with the same name and environment.

Serverless tried to update the existing cloudformation template but failed with the above message because the previously created resource and updated resources were not related in any way.

The solution for me was to find and delete the old cloud formation template (because I did not actually need it anymore) but an alternative would have been to change environment name